# Transfer raster values into point shapefile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, multipoint

I have a shapefile of points and I want to transfer the pixel values of a collection in GEE (e.g. Sentinel-2 max NDVI) to the corresponding points. 
With polygons it seems that this can be done with a reduction, does it work also for points?

Comment: Please provide a script, and a code editor link, where you're attempting to solve this. Make sure all your assets are shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, reductions can be done on point geometries — they'll always reduce just a single pixel. That is the usual way to get a pixel value out of an image when you have a point.

(For the reducers like `mean` and `max`, the result will of course be the same value as the pixel value, but other reducers like `frequencyHistogram` and `toList` will still return histograms, lists, and such, just with one element.)